# How to create only one executable jar with all dependencies inside it using maven shaded plugin instead of two

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jar, maven-plugin

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>SoclePDCFDR</groupId>
    <artifactId>SoclePDCFDR</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
        <version>14</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>


<build>

    <!-- <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources> -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                       <finalName>Test</finalName>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <shadedClassifierName>jar-with-dependencies</shadedClassifierName>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>com.sfdr.ms.pdc.FilesManagementMain</Main-Class>
                                <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make use of the below plugin as reference,

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.bitsWilp.BITSPilani</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <finalName>bitsWILP</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Ref: https://github.com/ramasamykasiviswanathan/BITSWilpAPI/blob/newAPIimpl/pom.xml

I coded for an API which has all dependencies bundled up.

Comment: For me its still creating two jars,<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>SoclePDCFDR</groupId>
 <artifactId>SoclePDCFDR</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> I have added this at the top of pom.xml its two jars with name SoclePDCFDR-0.0.--Snapshot and the one with  final name

Comment: Can you share me the complete content, where you are packaging, ideally it should work.

Comment: Hey, Just now checked my build the one with the final name is what which has dependency being packaged to it.